# pcb bypassing and grounding for NC7WZ04P6X

Tags: pcb, grounding, bypass

Here is a part of PCB with 8 NC7WZ04P6X (UHS Dual Inverter, SC-70-6), and zoom on right...

[image: pcb]

Signal frequency should be up to 6 MHz. Near each (between) NC7WZ04P6X will be 0.1 uF 0402 cap, and 1 uF 0603 (maybe 0402, will see later). Ground line (blue) is going on bottom pcb side and VCC (red) on top. At the end (supply), there is 10 uF cap, between VCC and GND (and GND is connected to ground plane). Is this bypassing / grounding on pcb good enough?

Edit: Here is PCB with 2 local ground planes, VCC on top, and GND on bottom, with 0402 or 0603 1 uF cap.

[image: pcb]

Comment: Depends on what the load of the NC7WZ04P6X is, what is the current output or load?

Comment: Output is going 3 cm on board, than on ribbon / flat cable (50 cm) to another board, and again 3 cm till on board device / chip (with input 50 kohm to ground). Few mA is enough for switching.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this bypassing / grounding on pcb good enough?

Probably good enough for most products in the 1960s and 1970s but today we use ground planes for 0 volt return wires wherever possible. This is to avoid EMC issues, either generation of or susceptibility to.